# Error saving child Entities with Composite Foreign Keys as Primary Key deserialized with JMS Serializer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a JSON object like this :

```
{
  "childEntity" : {
    "bar": "foo"
  },
  "someproperty" : "2.0"
}
```

I use the JMS Serializer bundle to deserialize this object and transform it to a Doctrine2 Object:

```
$myObject = $serializer->deserialize($jsonStringJustAbove, "My\FooBundle\Entity\masterEntity", 'json');
$myObject = $em->merge($myObject);
$myObject->persist($tour);
$myObject->flush();
```

Here is my "masterEntity" class :

```
class masterEntity {

 /**
     * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<My\FooBundle\Entity\childEntity>")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="childEntity", mappedBy="masterEntity", cascade={"remove", "persist", "merge"})
     */
    private $childentities;

 public function setChildEntities(ArrayCollection $childentities)
 {
     $this->childentities = $childentities;
 }

}
```

Here is my "childEntity" class :

```
class childEntity {

 /**
     * @JMS\Type("My\FooBundle\Entity\masterEntity")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\FooBundle\Entity\masterEntity", inversedBy="childEntities", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $masterEntity;

/**
     * @JMS\Type("My\FooBundle\Entity\barEntity")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\FooBundle\Entity\barEntity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $barEntity;

 public function setMasterEntity(masterEntity $masterEntity)
 {
     $this->masterEntity = $masterEntity;
 }

 public function setBarEntity(barEntity $barEntity)
 {
     $this->barEntity = $barEntity;
 }

}
```

My JSON object received doesn't exists in the database yet, as all childEntities.

I expect from the deserializer to prepare the masterEntity and all his children to be saved to the database.
My first question is : do the serializer and the merge function acts like this :

```
$masterEntity = new masterEntity();
$childEntity = new childEntity();
$childEntity->setMasterEntity($masterEntity);
$childEntity->setBarEntity($foo);
```

I'm not sure because I receive this error when trying to save the masterEntity (second code block):

```
Notice: Undefined index: 0000000069332c43000000007c145082 in ../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2740
```

Notes :
I use Symfony 2.1.8 with Doctrine 2.3.2 and JMS Serializer dev-master (as 4 March 2013)

Can you tell me if what I'm trying to do is correct, logic and possible ?
If yes, why do I have this error ? How to get rid of it ?

Thanks you.

Comment: You should have a look at : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html